# Can't load multiple document.write scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, document.write

I'm trying to load a multiple document.write scripts into a single document. Like this:

:DocWrite.js

```
document.write('<a href="#"><img src='myimage.gif'/></a>');
```

MyHTML.html

```
$('.myclass').each( function( index, element ){
    var script = unescape('%3Cscript src="'+DocWrite.js+'" type="text/javascript"%3E%3C/script%3E');
    $(element).html( script );

});
<div class="myclass">document.write loads image here</div>
<div class="myclass">stops here and hangs</div>
<div class="myclass">same</div>
```

The first div loads the script and the image is written inside but it stops after that. I would just change DocWrite.js but I don't have access to it. Any ideas how I can fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `document.body.innerHTML+="content to add"` instead of `document.write()`

Comment: I don't have access to DocWrite.js

Comment: Oh, then the only possibility I see is overwriting the `document.write` function, but I'm truly not sure if I should be recommending this as I have no idea if it would work or what the downsides are.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing some quotes around `DocWrite.js`, try this instead:

```
$('.myclass').each( function( index, element ){
    var script = unescape('%3Cscript src="' + 'DocWrite.js' + '"type="text/javascript"%3E%3C/script%3E');
    $(element).html( script );
});
```

I just added single quotes around "DocWrite.js". Without the quotes, the JavaScript interpreter will think that `DocWrite` is an object and that you're trying to access the `js` property on that object.